# Change toolbars according to the condition

Tags: xamarin.android, android-toolbar

I am working with xamarin android. I have a layout where initially a toolbar with edit will be visible, when user selects edit the current tool bar should be replaced with another toolbar. I have written code as following.

```
  public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {

            _localMenu = menu;

            var toolbar = _isMultiSelect ? Resource.Menu.MultipleFormsDeleteToolBarMenu : Resource.Menu.FormToolbarMenu;

            MenuInflater.Inflate(toolbar, menu);

            return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

   }
```

And when `Edit` option in first toolbar is selected, Iam calling `OnCreateOptionsMenu`

```
  else if (item.ItemId == Resource.Id.edit)
            {
                _isMultiSelect = true;
                OnCreateOptionsMenu(_localMenu);
            }
```

Here the problem is,instead of showing second toolbar... the `Edit` option in first toolbar is replaced by three dots and while tapping on those three dots Edit and Delete options are dislaying.

How can I change those toolbars acconding to the requirements?

Comment: In your Xml file have you declared `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` for your item in the menu?

Comment: Yes, I declared that @uprightbassfan78